# why I use summary() function in r cause error: Error in svd(X): infinite or missing values in 'x'."

Tags: r

I use a polr fuction in ordinal logit model and I want to look the result use summary(), it display the error:Error in svd(X): infinite or missing values in 'x'."
I have an ordinal regression of the variable add the square and cube term,the code like this:

```
fit<- polr(y ~ lev + I(lev^2) + I(lev^3) +
                     cash + I(cash^2) + I(cash^3) +
                     roa + I(roa^2) + I(roa^3) +
                     lnassets + I(lnassets^2) + I(lnassets^3) +
                     debttoebitda + I(debttoebitda^2) + I(debttoebitda^3) +
                     rent + I(rent^2) + I(rent^3) +
                     ppe + I(ppe^2) + I(ppe^3) +
                     soe +
                     auditor  +
                     cra +
                     Slope_norm + I(Slope_norm^2) + I(Slope_norm^3) +
                     RMSE_norm + I(RMSE_norm^2) + I(RMSE_norm^3) +
                     mb + I(mb^2) + I(mb^3) +
                     industry + yr, 
                   data = df_all,Hess=TRUE)
summary(fit)
```

the NA and infinity check for variables manifest no problem

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and some reproducible date?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kailong fan! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.